# dismo - Plotting individual predictor responses

Tags: r, maxent

I have a MaxEnt model implemented in `dismo` package. The package has the convenient function `response` to plot predictors' responses as the ones provided by the model html output, in R plotting style.

I would like to plot the predictor responses of the"single-predictor" models likewise (as the ones shown below in the html), either by adapting the `response` function or by directly accessing data, but I couldn't find a solution for either cases.

More specifically, I can find out where to retrieve the plotted values in the model object.

To be more clear, here below in blue the plots I'm referring to (from MaxEnt html output)

[image]

**EDIT:** here's a reproducible example

```
library(raster) 
library(dismo)

## create 5 dummy predictors layer and stack them
iterations <- 5
mn <- c(0:10)
stdev <- c(0:10)
preds <- list()
for(i in 1:iterations){
  xy <- matrix(rnorm(40000, mean=sample(mn, 1), sd=sample(stdev, 1)),200,200)
  preds[[i]] <- raster(xy, 8,9,45,46, crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
}
preds_stack <- stack(preds)

## create random locations and random background points
ext <- raster(matrix(0,1,1), 8,9,45,46, crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
ext <- as(ext, 'SpatialPolygons')
locations <- spsample(ext, 200, type='clustered') 
background <- spsample(ext, 2000, type='random') 

## run MaxEnt
argumemts <- c("-J", "-P", "askoverwrite=false", "threads=6")
mod <- maxent(x=preds_stack, p=locations, a=coordinates(background)[,1:2], args=argumemts)  
mod # opens html output
```

Comment: any reproducible example?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether this is what you are looking for, but: if you use `response()` specifying a single variable, the function will plot and *invisibly* return the *x, y*, data. Is that what you are looking for?

```
r <- response(mod, var="layer.1")
r

# recreate the plot:
plot(r, type="l", ylim=c(0,1), col=2)
```

If you want to look at the source code, check:

```
getMethod("response", "DistModel")
dismo:::.doResponse
```